How can i add custom html tag with features and styling in Nuxt Js 2 - Vue Js
I'm currently engaged in developing a significant Nuxt.js website for my company. My objective is to eliminate redundant HTML, CSS, and JS code across multiple pages. I'm actively researching methods to streamline code reuse and improve overall maintenance efficiency (Like custom tags with features).
